# UaException: status=Bad_NodeIdUnknown, message=The node id refers to a node that does not exist in the server address space

Tags: java, multithreading, opc-ua, milo

My problem seems easy by looking the error but it's not.
I use the library Milo for the OPCUA version 0.2.4), and when I try to get the Variable node, i got the following error (for node ns=3;s=CIR.SAV.03.H1QCA.Value) :

```
2023-04-18 10:57:09.439 ERROR 14012 --- [http-nio-8082-exec-5] c.s.o.ua.client.ClientOpcUa.OPC_TPS_GTC  : Ecriture de la commande ns=3;s=CIR.SAV.03.H1QCA.Value impossible : {}

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: UaException: status=Bad_NodeIdUnknown, message=The node id refers to a node that does not exist in the server address space.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
    at com.sup.opc.ua.client.ClientOpcUa.writeItems(ClientOpcUa.java:350)
    at com.sup.opc.OpcService.writeValues(OpcService.java:146)
    at com.sup.ws.service.PilotageEquipementService.writeOPC(PilotageEquipementService.java:186)
    at com.sup.ws.service.PilotageEquipementService.execute(PilotageEquipementService.java:133)
    at com.sup.ws.service.PilotageEquipementService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$50a3fe5d.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.sup.ws.service.PilotageEquipementService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8a9d258.execute(<generated>)
    at com.sup.ws.controller.CommandeController.execute(CommandeController.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.UaException: status=Bad_NodeIdUnknown, description=The node id refers to a node that does not exist in the server address space.
    at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.util.FutureUtils.failedUaFuture(FutureUtils.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.nodes.UaNode.lambda$getAttributeOrFail$12(UaNode.java:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:966)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:940)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1975)
    at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.client.UaTcpStackClient.lambda$receiveResponse$16(UaTcpStackClient.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.util.ExecutionQueue$PollAndExecute.run(ExecutionQueue.java:107)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
```

But in Prosys, I can confim the nodeId exist :
[Prosys image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpPA2.png)

Hereafter my code :

```
@Override
    public boolean writeItems(Map<ItemId, Object> itemsValues) {
        ItemId itemId = null;

        for(Entry<ItemId, Object> entry : itemsValues.entrySet()) {
            itemId = entry.getKey();
            DataValue dataValue = new DataValue(new Variant(entry.getValue()), null, null);

            NodeId id = newNodeId(itemId.getTag());
            try {
                VariableNode variableNode = autoReconnectController.getClient().getAddressSpace().getVariableNode(id).get();
                StatusCode code = variableNode.writeValue(dataValue).get();
                logger.info("Result code {} in the variable {} : {}", entry.getValue(), itemId.getTag(), code.getValue());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Ecriture de la commande {} impossible : {}", id.toParseableString(), e);
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;

    }

public NodeId newNodeId(String id) {
        return new NodeId(config.getNamespace(), id);
    }
```

But, when i don't use `getVariableNode(id).get()` but I use instead `createVariableNode(id)`, it's work fine and I can write in the OPCUA server.

The id is the same in both case.

Can you help me please ?

I tried :

- Remove the .Value
- Verify all the configurations of the server (in UaExpert it's 20 variables in 3 seconds), so it's not a server problem.
- Change node ID

I expect one thing :

- Remove my UaException

Answer (score 0):

Can you get a Wireshark capture? `getVariableNode(id)` does some extra work, fetching the type definition and trying to use it when creating a VariableNode, and there may be something missing from the server that shouldn't be.

It should also be noted that you are using quite an old version of Milo. It would be worth the time to upgrade.